# Why is the icon of my combined flair different than all my individual flairs?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, flair, combined-flair

When looking at this, I am a bit confused:

[image]

In the combined flair, you see the hash of my old email address. Above (and this holds for every stackexchange site I have an account for), you see the hash of my "new" email address, which I changed about 3 weeks ago. When I did so, I changed it for StackOverflow and then chose "Copy StackOverflow profile to all Stack Exchange accounts". Subsequently, all other Stack Exchange accounts also showed the new image, but not the combined flair. What do I have to do to change the combined flair too? Is this a bug?

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but I wonder if you've considered using a [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/)?

Comment: @JonEricson: I have, and decided against it.

Comment: You could set up a Gravatar that looks like your current icon (whichever one you prefer).  Just a thought.

Comment: If [you specify a different style](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/224454.png?theme=clean) for the flair the correct avatar is displayed. Seems like it's just the flair image that's being inappropriately cached.

Answer (score 1):

The generated flair image is cached for up to 24 hours.  It looks like your gravatar has updated correctly now that the cache has expired.

[image]